# Javascript - How do I add image data (byte array) to multipart POST request

Tags: javascript, image, file-upload, arrays, multipartform-data

I'm building a multipart POST request in Javascript that will be sent using AJAX, I need to add an image as part of the request:

```
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-27f7edea-e541-485f-9bfe-bf9e10b2d6a7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedFile"; filename="uploaded-image-a4784b4e-802a-4bed-8fc9-c2a5e038e04f.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

[Image Data Here]
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-27f7edea-e541-485f-9bfe-bf9e10b2d6a7--
```

I have the image as a byte array, but appending that directly didn't work, I tried converting each byte to its char code and appending it to the request but that didn't work either, the image would get uploaded but when I retrieve it the image is corrupted.

Any thoughts on how I can append the image data without resulting in a corrupted version?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use HTML5 [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest); like this:

```
// Utility to create a random string for multipart boundary
function randomString() {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        str += (Math.random().toString(16)+"000000000").substr(2,8);
    }
    return str;
}

function upload(filename, contentType, byteArray, success, error) {
    var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    var boundary = randomString();

    var blob = new Blob([
        "--boundary_" + boundary + "\n"
        + "Content-Type: " + contentType + "\n" 
        + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedFile\"; filename=\"" + filename + "\"\n\n",
        byteArray,
        "\n\n" 
        + "--boundary_" + boundary + "--"
    ], {type : "multipart/form-data; boundary=\"boundary_" + boundary + "\""});

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", url);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // if the upload is completed
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            // if HTTP status is "Created"
            if (request.status == 201) {
                // return the response
                success(request.response);
            } else {
                // return the request, which has status, statusText etc
                error(request);
            }            
        }
    };

    request.send(blob);
}
```